# Why is Naruto allowed to teach Rasengan to Konohamaru?

Tags: naruto

Kakashi tells Jiraiya that Rasengan is a dangerous technique after he stopped Naruto and Sasuke who fought for the first time. If it is that dangerous, then why was Naruto allowed to teach Rasengan to Konohamaru?

Comment: Rasengan isn't a Kinjutsu,
Rasengan is just a powerful A-Rank Jutsu.
Kakashi mentioned that Rasengan is dangerous because if Naruto's Rasengan clashed with Sasuke's Chidori ( in their battle in the hospital only ) Sasuke would Die.
Rasengan is an Technique developed by the Fourth Hokage in 3 Years, while Chidori is a technique developed by Kakashi when he was 6 years old only.

Comment: Since it's not a forbidden jutsu, I do not see a reason why he shouldn't be teaching it to Konohamaru. How else do you expect the jutsu to be passed over to the next generations? It's a powerful technique and deserves to be passed along, just like the Sexy-justu :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although Rasengan may be a very dangerous technique, it's not a forbidden technique, so anybody can teach it to everybody.

The Naruto wiki has the categories for [forbidden Jutsus](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kinjutsu):

> - Techniques that cause harm to the user themselves, such as opening the Eight Gates, which the mere use of is both highly useful as well as detrimental to the user.
> - Techniques that violate the laws of nature (e.g. the Summoning: Impure World Reincarnation, which reincarnates the dead with a human sacrifice).
> - Certain techniques that are known to cause massive collateral damage, such as the total destruction of a village and end with the death of everyone in it, thus the great moral ramifications of its potential lead many to labelling it as a forbidden technique.

Rasengan does not fit in any of these categories, so it's most likely not a forbidden Jutsu ;).

Comment: But Naruto is not a chunnin or Jounnin to teach a Genin. Is a genin allowed to teach jutsus?

Comment: @PraveenSharath Everyone is allowed to teach someone, why should it be forbidden^^. And even though Naruto is still a Genin, he is possibly one of the most experienced ninjas in konoha.

Comment: I don't think experienced is the right word (as he is still quite young) the strongest would be more accurate imo.

Comment: As an important side-note. If anyone should be allowed to teach anyone Rasengan it is Naruto. It *is* his father's jutsu afterall.